# Can you set an Android emulator to Night mode during instrumented test?

Tags: android, adb, android-espresso, instrumented-test

I'm writing instrumented android tests that take screenshots for the app's Play Store listing. I would like to be able to toggle night mode on the emulator, so I can get screen caps of the activity using both themes.

Is there any way to set an emulator to night mode strictly from an instrumented test?